# Windows 10 Start Menu - All apps Missing Icons

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I am currently "troubled" by the fact that some icons that do appear in the right place in Windows Explorer are missing from the Start Menu in Windows 10. For example, I create a folder with 3 icons in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs but out of them, only 2 are actually displayed in the Start Menu -> All apps.

[image: Missing Icons in Windows 10 Start Menu]

Any idea why this might be happening? I am sure it's not the "512" bug since I currently have only 262 items.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I presume you are still running build 10240?

Comment: I just updated to 10586 and the problem still persists.

Comment: One more thing (might be useful): I noticed that the shortcuts that are missing are for uninstalling. I could not find a single "Uninstall" shortcut in the entire start menu...

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I see the uninstall icons for some of the applications but not for all. Sorry...